# Replace all spaces and special symbols with dash in URL using PHP language

Tags: php

How to replace spaces and dashes when they appear together with only dash in PHP?

e.g below is my URL

```
http://kjd.case.150/1 BHK+Balcony- 700+ sqft. spacious apartmetn Bandra Wes
```

In this I want to replace all special characters with dash in PHP. In the URL there is already one dash after "balcony". If I replace the dash with a special character, then it becomes two dashes because there's already one dash in the URL and I want only 1 dash.

Comment: What do you want your url to become? `http://kjd.case.150/1-BHK-Balcony-700-sqft-spaciou-apartmetn-Bandra-West`?

Answer (score 50):

I'd say you may be want it other way. Not "spaces" but every non-alphanumeric character.
Because there can be other characters, disallowed in the URl (+ sign, for example, which is used as a space replacement)

So, to make a valid url from a free-form text

```
$url = preg_replace("![^a-z0-9]+!i", "-", $url);
```

Comment: Shouldn't those be forward slashes, rather than exclamation marks?

Comment: You've gotta slice off the domain name first, else you'll lose your dots.

Answer (score 2):

If there could be max one space surrounding the hyphen you can use the answer by [John](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627523/replace-all-spaces-and-special-symbols-with-dash-in-url-use-php-language/2627566#2627566). If there could be more than one space you can try using [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$str = preg_replace('/\s*-\s*/','-',$str);
```

This would replace even a `-` not surrounded with any spaces with `-` !!

To make it a bit more efficient you could do:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\s+-\s*|\s*-\s+/','-',$str);
```

Now this would ensure a `-` has at least one space surrounding it while its being replaced.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it for you

```
strtolower(str_replace(array('  ', ' '), '-', preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 s]/', '', trim($string))));
```

Comment: this one gets rid of the .pdf at the end too which you dont want to do

Answer (score 1):

Apply this regular expression `/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/, '-'` which will replace all non alphanumeric characters with `-`. Store it in a variable and again apply this regular expression  `/\-$/, ''` which will escape the last character.

Answer (score -1):

Its old tread but to help some one, Use this Function:

```
function urlSafeString($str)
{
    $str = eregi_replace("[^a-z0-9\040]","",str_replace("-"," ",$str));
    $str = eregi_replace("[\040]+","-",trim($str));
    return $str;
}
```

it will return you a url safe string